# Adding HTML to a Ruby on Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm not a RoR expert, trying to write my first gem which includes javascript, erb, etc. Is this possible, it seems like every tutorial and example code I can find only includes ruby code. If it is possible, what does the directory structure of the gem look like with javascript and erb files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide
>   functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is
>   actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application
>   class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine.
>
> Therefore, engines and applications can be thought of almost the same
>   thing, just with subtle differences, as you'll see throughout this
>   guide. Engines and applications also share a common structure.

Comment: Unfortunately the senior guy on the project is insisting on making a gem project and not a plugin/engine project. 

Having a lot of difficulty finding an example gem (or documentation) that includes both javascript and html files, and how to use them. At least this was helpful: https://gorails.com/episodes/creating-gems-for-frontend-javascript-libraries

Comment: @Gerry You can distribute an Engine as a Gem; many popular gems like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) are engines.